# How to check duplicates name in android database?

Tags: android, database, cursor, duplicate-data

I want to enter name and phone number from two edit text.i use two buttons to save and show it in emulator using list view.After entering name and when i click save button **how to check whether i have already entered the same name.** i am new to android explanation will be really helpful.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tbname+"("+Key_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Key_name+" TEXT,"+Key_mobile+" TEXT)");

}

public void n(String aa, String bb) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Key_name, aa);
    cv.put(Key_mobile, bb);
    db.insert(tbname, Key_name, cv);

    db.close();

}

public Cursor cr()

{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    String [] colms=new String[]{Key_id+" as _id",Key_name,Key_mobile};
    Cursor cur=db.query(tbname, colms, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    return cur;



}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start with changing your table definition by adding the NOT NULL and UNIQUE constraints.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tbname+"("+Key_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Key_name+" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,"+Key_mobile+" TEXT)");
```

Then you have a choice of methods to use for your insert.  You can use:

`insertOrThrow` will return the id of your new record, or -1 on an error (and a constraint failure of not having a unique name would be an error).

`insertWithOnConflict` will return the id of the new record OR the primary key of the existing row if the input param 'conflictAlgorithm' = CONFLICT_IGNORE OR -1 if any error.

Personally, I would use `insertWithOnConflict` with the CONFLICT_IGNORE flag set.  That way you can get the row id back for the duplicate record (as well as not letting the duplicate get entered).

Comment: Is there any aleternate method other than using UNIQUE...like comparing

Comment: That is what UNIQUE does, compares.  It's about as simple and minnimum code as you could wish for.  You could compare it outside the DB, but then it's twice the work.  Pull a cursor, do the comparison, if it's not there access the DB again to insert the data.  Make the DB work for you and use UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

Put `UNIQUE` in your table field definition an then use `insertOrThrow`. If you insert the same, `insertOrThrow` will cause an exception, you can intercept it.

Comment: While Inserting you have to be precise..where should i insert UNIQUE before keyname                                                                         

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tbname+"("+Key_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,UNIQUE "+Key_name+" TEXT,"+Key_mobile+" TEXT)");